# Align Userform to cells in Excel

Tags: excel, userform, vba

I'm attempting to position a userform (named UserForm1) in Excel to align with cell references in Excel. If I initialize the form using the first code below, the userform is correct size positioned in the centre of the screen in Excel.

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

With Me
  .Width = 200
  .Height = 170
End With

End Sub
```

However, I want to resize to align the userform so that it covers cells B3:D15. I've tried

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

With Me
.Top = Sheet1.Range("B3").Top
.Left = Sheet1.Range("B3").Left
.Width = Sheet1.Range("B3").Offset(0, 4).Left - Sheet1.Range("B3").Left
.Height = Sheet1.Range("B3").Offset(12, 0).Top - Sheet1.Range("B3").Top
End With

End Sub
```

but the userform appears over the ribbon (Excel zoom is at 100%.)

Is there a way to do this properly taking into account screen resolution/zoom size?

Answer (score 3):

First I apologize for bringing back this old thread from the dead, but others answers for this problem on SO either doesn't work perfectly or only on specific situations (fullscreen, etc.).
After looking for answers to this questions on many forums and others SO related questions, I found some simple code on a french forum that works just fine for 32bits version of excel (office 365).

In a module:

```
Option Explicit
 
Private Declare Function GetDC& Lib _
"user32.dll" (ByVal hwnd&)
Private Declare Function GetDeviceCaps& _
Lib "gdi32" (ByVal hDC&, ByVal nIndex&)
 
Sub UserFormAlign()
    ' 1 inch = 72 points for usually 96 or 120 dpi
    Dim x#, y#, w#, h#
    x = GetDeviceCaps(GetDC(0), 88) / 72
    y = GetDeviceCaps(GetDC(0), 90) / 72
    With UserForm1
        .StartUpPosition = 0
        .Left = (ActiveWindow.PointsToScreenPixelsX(ActiveCell.Left * x) * 1 / x) + ActiveCell.Width
        .Top = (ActiveWindow.PointsToScreenPixelsY(ActiveCell.Top * y) * 1 / y) + ActiveCell.Height
        .Show 'if not already shown
    End With
End Sub
```

The code above can be easily adapted to be launched from the `UserForm` by replacing the `With UserForm1` with `With Me`, and also removing the `.Show` if needed (no point in trying to show itself since there are chances it is already on screen).

Comment: This worked great for me. Thanks for sharing. :) Glad you found it and shared it.

Comment: Here's an update for 64-bit Excel, which I imagine should be everyone now. The `Declare` statement needs to have `PtrSafe` added to it, like so: `Private Declare PtrSafe Function GetDC Lib "user32" (ByVal hwnd As Long) As Long` and `Private Declare PtrSafe Function GetDeviceCaps Lib "gdi32" (ByVal hDC As Long, ByVal nIndex As Long) As Long`.